# Unable get sound from Fedora 19

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, sound-card, fedora-19

I just switched from windows to fedora 19 as my distro. It's running fine but I am having issues with my sound card i.e i am unable to hear anything. 
I Googled for a fix or procedure on how to resolve this issue, and tried many things that people suggested but it didn't get the work done.

I am using ES1978 Maestro 2E as my sound card, since my built in intel soundcard is broken. This sound card  worked perfectly in windows.

What I have tried so far..

1. Checked my sound setting whether I have the correct output device selected or not it was correct one.
2. opened up terminal and used alsa utils alsamixer to check whether the sound card has been detected and initialized or not, the sound card was detected but it was off so i toggled it on. but i am not able to adjust the slider on the playback controls using the arrow keys.

   [link to image alsamixer output](https://plus.google.com/photos/102573009534257298543/albums/5932759704186986993/5932759707092205186?banner=pwa&pid=5932759707092205186&oid=102573009534257298543)
3. And lastly i used amixer to set the values manually. I set the values for capture source and capture volume.

   [link to image for amixer output](https://plus.google.com/photos/102573009534257298543/albums/5932759704186986993/5932759709970728018?banner=pwa&pid=5932759709970728018&oid=102573009534257298543)

But None of these worked for me.

super user didnt allow me to upload images directly because my rep is lower that 10 so i have pasted the links for the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

At [linuxaudio.org](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/all/ess_maestro_2e_linux_driver_for_alsa) there is a driver for your soundcard.

And at Launchpad there is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1019921) (it is for Ubuntu, but you could add your information there, if you want, they are searching for people with that soundcard).

May you should try other linux distros (Ubuntu and older Fedoras). You do not have to install them, just copy them on your usb pendrive (or on CD-R if you still use them) and boot from your usb pendrive or CD.

I tell this, because in 2009 a user in a [Ubuntu forum managed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=796038) to hear sound from this soundcard. And if you know which was the last version of a distribution that worked with you soundcard, you know which was the last linux kernel version and alsa version and so on.

And you could write to the author of the above mentioned soundcard driver and to the user in the Ubuntu forum, asking them, if their soundcard works with recent distributions and how they managed that.

You can find old distributions here: http://distrowatch.org/

If you find a solution, please answer your own question, so that other owners of this soundcard could benefit from your effort.